# PHP Get date from form POST and convert to Monday 14 September 2015

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, date

I have a search form to search by date
in the search results page I have the follow code:

I get the POST vars

```
$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_POST['dd']);
$month = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_POST['dm']);
$year = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_POST['da']);
```

Now I echo the date with set locale

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
echo strftime("%d de %B del %Y", strtotime('$day-$month-$year'));
?>
```

The result I get is

```
31 de diciembre del 1969
```

What can be wrong?

EDIT
The date is comming from HTML form like this:

```
dd = 30 (day)
dm = 08 (month)
da = 2015 (year)
```

all together gives

```
2015-08-30 (joining all 3 with $year-$month-$day)
```

Comment: Single quotes bad, double quotes good.... at least when you're wrapping variables in quotes - [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and read the __Note__ `Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.`

Comment: What do you mean? is better to use double quotes in $_POST['dd']); ?

Comment: No, you're not trying to expand any PHP variables in `'dd'`. I mean `echo strftime("%d de %B del %Y", strtotime("$day-$month-$year"));` Double quotes where you're trying to expand `$day`, `$month` and `$year`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot, the problem was just the quotes. Can you please answer it so future users get solutions thanks